# EF 4 to EF 5 Database Authentication

Tags: silverlight-5.0, ria

I have an application developed using EF4, .Net 4.5, Silverlight 5, Ria services.

I want to upgrade from EF4 to EF5, a lot of differences specially on the DBContext.

I was using a custom database authentication in EF4 by implementing the **IAuthentication** interface in my **AuthenticationDomainService** class and use the extended **WebContextBase** class on the client.

I don't know what are the equivalent to these steps on EF5 as I don't have a DomainService class nor AuthenticationDomainService class.

Can anyone give me directions to resolve the issue!!

Answer (score 0):

I was not getting DomainService class due to the absence of WCFRIA.EntityFramework.5.0.0.1 package.

I have install it and I can now have the authentication created.

Hope it can help anyone else.